# Submitting dynamically created input field in django

Tags: django, python-3.x

am working on a project with Django, i dynamically created an input field and am trying to submit it, but i could not do so, i searched online and i saw that it could be done with formset_factory but when i tried it, i got this error

```
CatName = int(float(request.POST.get('CatName')))
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

here is my code

the form.html

```
<form action="." method="post" id="PostCat__form">{% csrf_token %}
                <input type="hidden" name="deyHidden" value="category_hidden">
                {% comment %} {{ catForm | crispy }}       
                <input type="hidden" name="deyHidden" value="category_hidden"> {% endcomment %}
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="CatName[]" >
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="CatName[]" >
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="CatName[]" >
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="CatName[]" >

                <div class="form-group">
                    <h6 id="PostCat__show"></h6>
                    <img src=" {% static 'images/ajax-loader.gif' %}" style="Display:none;" id="PostCat__img">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit"   id="PostCat__submit">Create</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

the model.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    CatName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

the view.py

```
        myFormCat = CatPostForm(request.POST)
        CatName = int(float(request.POST.get('CatName')))
        # print(CatName)
        formset = formset_factory(FormsetForm, CatName=CatName)(request.POST)

        if myFormCat.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            for form_c in formset:
                if not form_c.cleaned_data['CatName']:
                    Category.objects.get_or_create(CatName=CatName)
                    response_data = {
                        'SType': 'success',
                        'message': "Saved Successfully"
                    }                
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
```

the forms.py

```
class CatPostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta: 
        model=Category
        fields = ['CatName']
```

pls how can i do it so that i can successfully submit the form,

Answer (score 0):

on your `views.py`

```
from django.forms import formset_factory
CatPostFormSet = formset_factory(CatPostForm)
catformset = CatPostFormSet() #this goes to your page context. do the validations here also after the post
```

on your `form.html`

```
<form method="post">
    {{ formset.management_form }}
        {{formset}}
</form>
```

Comment: raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key)
django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'CatName'

Comment: use one input as                 `<input type="text" class="form-control" name="CatName" >`

Comment: I want to send multiple input field with the tag name CatName that's why I used CatName[]

Comment: then u need a formset_factory. Take a look at the official doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/formsets/

Comment: I did but didn't understand it

Comment: I updated the answer. Please start from this and take a look at the official doc.

Comment: i got this error     CatName = int(float(request.POST.get('CatName')))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'jnk'

Comment: the old code doesnt make sense anymore. U need to handle formset now...

Comment: OK but how can I use it in the views.py